# How can I access parameters in angular directive link function without $watch?

Tags: angularjs, directive

```
<cat color="black"></cat>

app.directive('cat', function() {
   return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
         color: '='
      },
      link: function(scope) {
         alert(scope.color)
      }
   }
});
```

It will alert an undefined message.

I know this is feasible if a use a $watch, but I don't want, because the parameters can have dependencies with each other.

What I want is like Vue's mounted function or something similar, inside which we can handle with parmameters directly.

Is there anyone knows how to reach such goal? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When defining `scope: {}`, you have 3 different options for your properties.

1. `=`.  This will set the property in the directive equal to the `$scope` property named in the directive definition, in a two way relationship.  i.e. given `color: '='` and `<cat color="black">`, the parent directive will look for a property `$scope.black` and attempt to assign that property to `color`.  Changes to `color` will change `black`, and visa versa.
2. `@`.  This will set the property in the directive equal to the *value* of the variable named in the directive, in a one way relationship.  i.e.  `<cat color="black">` will set `color == "black"`, immediately and at the time of initialization.
3. `&`.  This will set the property in the directive equal to a function in the parent.  i.e. `<cat color="black">` will set `color == black`, and `color()` will execute `black()`.

given this, to accomplish what you are expecting, you have 3 options:

- Create a `$scope.black` property in the parent, and set it to a string value.
- Pass your value as an anonymous string object, i.e. `<cat color="'black'">`.
- Change your `scope` definition to `color: '@'`.

Examples: http://plnkr.co/edit/byxhKtAewLgOrFpRU8dg?p=preview